# How to prevent table rows from rebuilding on update

Tags: reactjs

I have a react table with an editable row that contains a custom form component. When a new  row is added or removed to the table, MyForm rebuilds if it's *below* the new or deleted row, but does rebuild not if its *above* it. Here is an example to clarify...

Example A, **good** case:

time 1:

```
<tr key="1"><td>one</td></tr>
<tr key="2"><td>two</td></tr>
<tr key="edit"><td><MyForm/></td></tr>
<tr key="3"><td>three</td></tr>  // <--- this row will be removed @ time2
```

time 2:

```
<tr key="1"><td>one</td></tr>
<tr key="2"><td>three</td></tr>
<tr key="edit"><td><MyForm/></td></tr>
```

In this case MyForm component did not rebuild and its local state did not get wiped out. This is what I want.

Example B, **bad** case:

time 1:

```
<tr key="1"><td>one</td></tr>
<tr key="2"><td>two</td></tr> // <--- this row will be removed @ time2
<tr key="edit"><td><MyForm/></td></tr>
<tr key="3"><td>three</td></tr>
```

time 2:

```
<tr key="1"><td>one</td></tr>
<tr key="edit"><td><MyForm/></td></tr>
<tr key="3"><td>three</td></tr>
```

MyForm got rebuild and my local state was clobbered. This is bad because as I might be making edits to the fields. My understand is that reactjs should NOT rebuild components that don't need updating and this is handled with **key**. Why is MyForm being rebuilt simply because its siblings that come before it are being changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a Object vs Array typing issue with how I was building the rows in the render call

What should have been
[Object, Object, Object]

Was
[Array[2], Object]

Because of this:

```
let tableRows = rows.map(row=>{
    let tdRow = <tr key={row.id}></tr>
    if(this.state.editId === row.id) {
      return [tdRow , <tr key={row.id + '_edit'}><MyForm/></td>]
    }
    else {
      return tdRow 
    }
})

return <table><tbody>{tableRows}</tbody></table>;
```

Lesson is: Don't return an array from  map call

Comment: So, I'm really sure the best way to fix this since jsx requires a root dom node for each variable correct? I want to return two <tr> tags from the map call when the edit row is reached.

Comment: I changed the map to a forEach and just appended the dom nodes to an array. Best not to use map if you don't return a 1:1 amount of things for the list of iteration

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent components from re-rendering by implementing https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate

However no matter if your component was re-rendered or not, it should never loose state, but in case of forms their own state is not always controlled by react unless you apply this https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/controlled-input-null-value.html

Comment: Thanks! shouldcomponentupdate would indeed prevent rebuilding but I don't have the right info being passed in because its the parent component that should not be rebuilding it in the first place. Its up to the parent in this case to not clobber the child.